# I can't seem to figure out how to create an object from a class

Tags: java

I could use some help as I am really stuck. I'm doing this homework assignment and I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. Here are the exact instructions;

1. Create an Eclipse project named “Java1Final_LastName”.
2. Create an abstract class named “Customer”.
3. Add 2 private fields to the class, “name” and “id”.
4. Add a constructor that takes 2 arguments, “aName” and “aId”.
5. Add the following abstract method “public abstract int discount();”
6. Create a Child class of Customer named “OnlineCustomer”.
7. Add a constructor that takes 2 arguments, name, id.
8. Write the body of the inherited abstract discount method.
9. Online customers get a 10% discount.
10. Create a JFrame class for your user interface named “CustomerJFrame”.
11. Assign "Java 1 Final by lastName" to the frame title.
12. Add a JLabel and JTextField for the Name.
13. Add a JLabel and JTextField for the Id.
14. Add a JLabel for the message output.
15. Add a JButton for the Submit button.
16. Add an ActionPerformed Listener for the submit button.
17. When the button is selected, create the OnlineCustomer object using the name and id from your JTextFields. Display the name, id and discount in the OnlineCustomer object in the message JLabel
18. Create a class named “CustomerApp” that has the main method.
19. Create an object of your CustomerJFrame class.

So I think I am stuck on #17. I'm not really sure what it is asking. Here is everything I have done so far. I think I'm close, but I feel like I'm missing something important!

-Customer Class-

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public abstract class Customer 
{
// private fields
private String name;
private String idnumber;

// overloaded constructor with 2 arguments
public Customer(String aName, String aIdNumber)
{
    this.name = aName;
    this.idnumber = aIdNumber;
}

//abstract method
public abstract int discount();
}
```

-Online Customer Class-

```
public class OnlineCustomer extends Customer
{
private int discount=10;

//OnlineCustomer constructor
public OnlineCustomer(String aName, String aIdNumber) 
{ 
    //use parent constructor
    super(aName, aIdNumber);
}

//body of inherited method
public int discount()
{
    return discount;
}

}
```

-CustomerJFrame Class-

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CustomerJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//fields
private JLabel nameJLabel;
private JTextField nameJTextField;

private JLabel idJLabel;
private JTextField idJTextField;

private JLabel outputJLabel;

private JButton submitJButton;

private final int WIDTH = 300;
private final int HEIGHT = 250;

public CustomerJFrame()
{
    // call the super class constructor
    super("Java 1 Final by Vokurka");

    // set the height and width of the JFrame
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // set the default close operation to end the program.
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);

    // set flow layout
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    // create a label and add it to the frame
    nameJLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
    add(nameJLabel);

    // create a text field and add it to the frame
    nameJTextField = new JTextField("", 15);
    nameJTextField.selectAll();
    add(nameJTextField);

    // create a label and add it to the frame
    idJLabel = new JLabel("Id: ");
    add(idJLabel);

    // create a text field and add it to the frame
    idJTextField = new JTextField("", 15);
    idJTextField.selectAll();
    add(idJTextField);

    // create and add a message JLabel
    outputJLabel = new JLabel("Customer: Name, ID:000, Discount: 0%");
    add(outputJLabel);

    // create and add a JButton
    submitJButton = new JButton("Submit");
    submitJButton.addActionListener(this);
    add(submitJButton);

    // set the JFrame to visible
    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    // get the user data from the JTextFields
    String nameresults = nameJTextField.getText();
    String idresults = nameJTextField.getText();

    // set the results to the message JLabel
    outputJLabel.setText("Customer:" + nameresults, "ID:" + idresults, "Discount: 10%");
}
}
```

-CustomerApp Class-

```
public class CustomerApp 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // create a JMyFrame object
    CustomerJFrame aFrame = new CustomerJFrame();
}

}
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I have an error in CustomerJFrame on setting the output text if it helps. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Posting the error message, and possibly narrowing down the code in question instead of posting your entire application, will help you get an answer.

Comment: Its better you ask something precise. Nobody wants to do somebody's hometasks)))

Comment: I'm not really sure what is wrong. The error message is this;

The method setText(String) in the type JLabel is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String)

I would ask specifics if I knew what was wrong, sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Like the message says: you are passing it 3 arguments when it only expects 1.

Comment: Is there someway for it to take 3? I'm kinda confused. Why would my instructor ask for it to take 3 if it can only take one?

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor? Its his job, not ours.

Answer (score 0):

Like the message says: you are passing a method 3 arguments when it only expects 1:

```
outputJLabel.setText("Customer:" + nameresults, "ID:" + idresults, "Discount: 10%");
```

Instead, concatenate these together into a single string (or something like):

```
outputJLabel.setText("Customer:" + nameresults + " ID:" + idresults + " Discount: 10%");
```

Comment: I did not know " placement made a difference. Thank you! I really appreciate the help!

Comment: The `"` placement makes no difference. I just added an extra space so the `ID` and `Discount` are separated from the preceding text. The important change here is using `+` instead of `,` to concatenate the bits of the strings together.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you create the object like it says in the steps?

```
OnlineCustomer oc = new OnlineCustomer(nameJTextField.getText(), idJTextField.getText());
```

Comment: Can you please post it as a comment if it is for clarification ?

Comment: @Phani Sure I'll re-edit it now, but I couldn't before because I didn't have 50 reputation at the time to submit comments.